# Get vector position of single face from capture attribute node

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]
[image]

I have a cone which is being positioned relative to the face which has points distributed on it. I want it to animate on the normal position of that face. The problem I had was that it always starts at the world origin regardless of which face I choose to use.

I tried to add a capture attribute node but this outputs a field, I have tried various ways to change this to a single vector so that I can position the cone in the centre of the face I choose via the index.

How would I modify my node tree to achieve this?

Comment: Try to plug "an Index selector" (just an Input/Constant/Integer node) in the "Sample Index" nodes following the "Distribute Points on Faces" node to specify the face you are targetting, instead of leaving the "Index" socket unplugged. I am running out of time for details right now, but could you have a look to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/309385/177431) ? I think it might help you.

Comment: About the "red" link, I strongly recommend to read this post: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another)

Comment: @StefLAncien thanks for helping me here, I have tried an integer in the Sample Index nodes but still doesn't work for me. Will this actually select a face as the Distribute Points on Faces node ouputs points not a mesh. Maybe i'm just not getting it.

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ to give it a try ?

Comment: just add a set position node before or after (i am not totally sure which is right) and then plug in the end of the red line to the offset of that node. Then it should work. -> this only solves the "red line" problem, pls provide blend file

Comment: Would you like a single cone centred on  the selected face, or one cone per random point on the selected face, as proposed by [Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/310158/177431) ?

Comment: @chris yes I want a single cone centred on the face I've chosen to scatter points over. Then I'm animating the cone so that it starts at the centre of selected face using the face normal direction. So i don't want it to go inside the mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

##### Objective

To animate a single cone along the normal of a selected by index face.
[image: Animated cone]

##### Geometry Nodes graph

[image: GN Graph]
**1.** The targetted face is identified by its *Index*. For the demo, an *Input/Constant/Integer* node is used.
**2.** The face **centre** coordinates are recovered from the receiving geometry using a *Sample Index* node set in *Face* domain and linked to a *Position* node.
**3.** The face **normal** coordinates are recovered from the receiving geometry using an other *Sample Index* node set in *Face* domain and linked to a *Normal* node. This vector is converted to a rotation through an *Align Euler to Vector* node. Its *Axis* property is set to Z because the cone axis is aligned to Z axis.
**4.** The cone periodic displacement along the normal, between 0 and 1, is computed as:
$$ \frac{1}{2} \left\{ \sin{(\omega t)} + 1 \right\}$$
where $t$ is the frame count. With $\omega$ set to 0.15, the oscillation period is $2\pi/\omega=42$ frames.
**5.** The unitary displacement vector is computed by rotating the unit vector along the cone axis (i.e. Z axis) with a *Vector Rotate* node. *(NB: the normal from step 3 could be used instead)*.
**6.** The position of the cone origin is computed by adding the scaled displacement to the face centre position.
**7.** A *Transform Geometry* node is used to specify the position and the orientation of the cone.

##### Resources

[image]

Comment: This does what I need and works with my setup also, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

[image]

result:

[image]

i separate the face as you did, then distribute faces on that face and then just instance cones on the points and adapt rotation via align euler to vector. Hope it helps.

Comment: As usual you were helpful, but I wanted the cone to be on a particular face which is why accepted a different answer.